# Inequalities $x/y > 0$

Tags: inequality

I am sure I am just being stupid but I can't get the illogic in this problem:
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{x}{y} &> 0\\
\frac{x}{y}\cdot y &> 0\cdot y\\
x &> 0   
\end{align}
$$
However:  when $x= -1,\; y= -1$   ;  $-1/-1 > 0$  is true  but  $x = -1 > 0$ is not!

Comment: if $y<0$ and you multiply $\frac x y > 0$ by $y$, you have to reverse the $>$. Then you get $x< 0$.

Comment: Try in English: when is the quotient of two real numbers positive? Like their product. When they are both positive, or both negative.

Comment: Welcome to MSE!

For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), 
[here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and 
[here](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex).

Answer (score 1):

We address for which values of $x, y$ the following inequality holds $$xy > 0$$

Note that when you multiply by $y$, when $y<0$ then $y\cdot \dfrac xy> y\cdot 0 \implies x < 0$. That is, multiplying each side of an inequality by a negative number reverses the direction of the inequality.

So, the inequality $\;\dfrac xy > 0\;$ holds if and only if

- **both** $ x > 0$ **and** $ y>0$,

**OR**

- **both** $x\lt 0$ **and** $y < 0$.

Indeed, the inequality holds for all pairs, and only those ordered pairs $(x, y)$ that are located strictly within the first and third quadrants of the Cartesian Plane (excluding, of course, the $x, y$ axes).

Comment: Duh.. of course it does... thank you!!!!!

Comment: @amWhy: even the OP agrees, but for +1 :-)

Answer (score 1):

$\dfrac{x}{y}>0$ is not true for all $x,y$. It is **NOT** true when

i) $y=0$

ii) $x=0$

iii) $x<0$ and $y>0$

iv) $x>0$ and $y<0$

So you can only multiply $\dfrac{x}{y}>0$ by $y$ on both sides of the inequality if the above conditions are excluded. In general $\left(\dfrac{x}{y}\times y\right) > \left(0 \times y\right)$ is not true for all $y$. So you cannot do this to conclude $x>0$.

Comment: also very insightful... thank you!